# what are the real effects to change JSESSIONID?

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security

I am working on a java application using spring security.

I want to avoid the session fixation, but the session fixation solution found on the docs seem not to be working as expected... [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-session-fixation)

So, I did this on my login

```
final HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session != null && !session.isNew()) {
            session.invalidate();
        }
```

Works great and changes the JSESSIONID everytime I call the login page...

But once I am logged in, I can call the login page again, get another JSESSIONID and still be logged in, I can just click on the back button and come back to the logged users area.

It does change the JSESSIONID, my question is, shouldnt it have a bigger effect? like invalidate my session or log me out?

When I call the log out form it does log the user out and works as expected, I am just wondering if changing the JSESSIONID has a real effect or does nto matter.

ANy idea?

I am using security 3.2

Comment: Spring security [does that automatically](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/html/ns-config.html#ns-session-fixation). What are you trying to achieve here? Sorry to to be blunt, but you don't seem to have the requisite knowledge to implement security so it would be prudent to rely on tried and tested code.

Comment: Hello, at my app it is not being done automatically, I tried to implement it but probably didnt do it well, any idea how to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spring's `session` is mapped to `JSESSIONID`. so if a customer would have session state beans, they would be lost after changing `JSESSIONID`. 
even though documentation tells

> Spring Security protects against this automatically by creating a new
>   session when a user logs in

you can explicitly set configuration for session fixation by adding this

```
<security:session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="fixation" />
```

and defining `fixation` bean with `SessionFixationProtectionStrategy` class